# Is it possible to have a JPA entity that doesn't have a table itself, but is an aggregate of other entities?

Tags: jpa, domain-driven-design

Is it possible to have an entity such as

```
@Entity
class Aggreate {
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
}
```

where aggreate itself is not stored in a seperate table, but B C D are? Aggregate will be queryable and will cascade operations to its parts. I will use such a class to manage B, C, D without exposing their methods to everyone.

Comment: How are B, C and D represented in the database?

Comment: Think of it this way, how are you going to query or persist a certain Aggreate instance?

Comment: How about instead of introducing the concept of an aggregate in the code make one of the entities an aggregate root and make all the entities within an aggregate cascadely updated (`CascdadeType.ALL`)?

Comment: Sure but then there will be an aditional meaningless table (meaningless from the point of database). Maybe a solution is to query b,c,d seperately and build aggregate from them when its needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using construction of an aggregate result class as described in [Result Classes (Constructor Expressions)](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_)

> JPA supports wrapping JPQL query results with instances of custom result classes. This is mainly useful for queries with multiple SELECT expressions, where custom result objects can provide an object oriented alternative to representing results as Object[] elements.
>
> Any class with a compatible constructor can be used as a result class. It could be a JPA managed class (e.g. an entity class) but it could also be a lightweight 'transfer' class that is only used for collecting and processing query results.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like those are not entities per se, to be sure a knowledge of the domain is needed.
If they aren't needed as entities maybe the [@Embeddable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html) can help.